# How to perform git checkout to some branches and then git pull using Jenkins for private repository?

Tags: jenkins, github

I have couple of branches, say

- branch1 
  branch2
  branch3

Here, current branch is branch1, i want to perform the following operation
git checkout branch2 and then 
git pull origin branch2 using Jenkins.

Comment: Those commands are executed in a shell context, so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276351/how-can-i-execute-shell-script-in-jenkinsfile

Comment: But, while taking pull on git branch it will ask for git user credentials, how to automate that part?

Comment: Use `git config` to store credentials: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: There are multiple git users all have different repository access, we can't configure all git credentials using git config in servers.

Comment: Are you saying that all of your developers all work on the same, single development machine?

Comment: yes, in the same development machine.

Comment: Each user can set up an environmental variable to store their user.name and user.email: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables